# HttpHandler for static image is not getting called when file does not exist

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I have httpHandler that handles the jpg file. When a request for a jpg image comes to server it is forwareded to handler. This works fine until i implemented finger printing for google page speed rule.

Now it gets called for http://static2.localnatamam.com/Uploaded/Image/Image_Haroon_ur_Rasheed_78.jpg

but not for

http://static2.localnatamam.com/Uploaded/Image/_SFP634229374826528000EFP_Image_Haroon_ur_Rasheed_78.jpg

First file exist in directory but second does not exist as the second URL is finger printed and i want to get the request in Handler but handler never gets evoked.

I think its might be IIS 7 configuration that is returning 404 rather than passing it to handler.

Please any advise or configuration that can route request to httphandler no matter if exist or not.

I am using asp.net MVC 2 with IIS 7 integreated Mode with target framework 4.0 in local enviornment so both of above URL will not open for any body.

My handler is simple IHttpHandler with the following IIS configuration

```
<add name="CrossDomainResourceHandler" type="MvcApplication3.HttpHandlers.CrossDomainResourceHandler" path="*.jpg" verb="*" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="false" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%path%\aspnet_isapi.dll"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have this in your web.config  file:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  </system.webServer>
```

runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests will tell IIS to route every request through the .net pipeline so that your module will pick this request up since by default static resources like .jpg are configured to not run through asp.net.